# How does InfoGAN learn latent categorical codes on MNIST

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks

While reading the [InfoGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03657.pdf) paper and implement it taking help from a previous implementation, I'm having some difficulty understanding how it learns the discrete categorical code when trained on MNIST.

The [implementation](https://github.com/pianomania/infoGAN-pytorch) we tried to follow uses a target as a randomly generated integer from 0 to 9. My doubt is this: how can it learn categorical information if from the start it's learning using a loss which takes in random values.

If this implementation is wrong, then what should the target be while training the Q network, when using the categorical-cross-entropy loss on the output logits?